# PHP - fetching and inserting inside the loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a problem. Im using a while loop. I placed a  inside the query $rows['price']. How do I submit the entire inserted values inside the loop to a table?. It has 5 results.

```
page1.php

        <?php

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table where id = '$ID'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

        echo '<form action = "page2.php" name = "add" method = "post">';
        echo "<b>Price:</b> ";
        echo '<input size = "1" type="text" name="price" value = ""/>';
        echo "%";
        echo "<br/>";

        }

        ?>

    <input type="submit" name="price" value="SUBMIT"/>
    </form>
```

The output would be like this.

Price: __ %
Price: __ %
Price: __ %
Price: __ %
Price: __ %
|SUBMIT|

```
page2.php

             <?php


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $price = $_POST['price'];

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO items_tbl(price) VALUES('$price');


         ?>
```

Somehow it worked a little. I inputed values in the form from 90,80,70,60,50. But the only one inserted in the table is the last, at the bottom (50). The rest dont.

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (_mysql_*_ functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (_mysqli_*_ functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: I know, im still learning the basic stuff in php. Im planning the use mysqli anyways after ive learned them enough

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this, the `<form>` tag should be outside `while` loop and you have to put `$row['price']` inside `value`

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM table where id = '$ID'");

echo '<form action = "page2.php" name = "add" method = "post">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo "<b>Price:</b> ";
    echo '<input size = "1" type="text" name="weight'.$row['price'].'" value = ""/>';
    echo "%";
    echo "<br/>";

}

?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

In **page2.php** use this

```
$val = implode(",", $_POST);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO items_tbl(price) VALUES('$val');
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: You have to input the value which is not from the while loop query -_-

Comment: lets say, I inputed in the form the value 90,80,70,60,50 then all of this will be inserted to the table altogether

Comment: Sory for not clarifying enought -_- the page1.php calls the ID in order I can insert  a price in a separate table in page2.php